# onsenui on mobile devices and firefox

Tags: cordova, user-interface, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

I am using the new Onsen UI for PhoneGap
http://onsenui.io/
and I like it. But it is not able to work fine on browsers other than chrome.

The  for example do not react, when you try to swipe in Firefox. This effect also occurs on mobile devices, where Chrome is not used.

Here my tests:

1. Samsung S3 Webbrowser Chrome - ons-sliding-menu - working
2. Firefox 27.0.1 - ons-sliding-menu - not working
3. IE 11 - ons-sliding-menu - not working
4. Windows Phone 7.5 Browser - ons-sliding-menu - not working

You can also test it by calling following site:
http://onsenui.io/docs/#sliding-menu

Just open it with any browser other than Chrome.
Here you can see, that only chrome is supported. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on supporting other browsers beside webkit based ones.

Can you confirm on your browsers?

http://onsenui.github.io/demo_dev/sliding_menu_demo.html

Comment: hi Tamura, could you please confirm the ONSEN UI also works on Windows Phone? Cheers